# Extracting Magic out of Magic field

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

In a series like *Harry Potter*, magic is an entity that exists predominantly but still portrayed mysterious and rather unclear in its complete origins.

In my world too I am creating a similar sort of magic but I want to provide a detailed explanation of what magic really is and how it works. I think magic as a field of energy with an absolute total magnitude for all over it's domain and varying only within the limits set in the domain. This might resemble quantum fields of Quantum Field Theory (QFT). In QFT, a particular particle is an excitation of the concerned quantum field. Likewise, an excitation of particular magnitude in the *magic field* would produce an associated *magic action*. Magic would be a field prevalent everywhere. Physics asserts that whenever you have to work, you have to *expend* energy. This energy is just a conversion of one form to the other. But the main thing is that there is always a **cause** that makes the **effect** occur. Every physical action can be traced to every other physical action on the classical level.

What I am imagining is that with Magic as a field everywhere, we might be able to do useful work like lifting, dragging, pushing, etc. by not physical or mechanical or electrical means but instead by extracting the precise quantities of *magic* out of the *magic field*. In a way it should be able to replace the role of physical forces.

I want to know how could I effectively as well as conveniently produce such a disturbance in the magic field to carry out the desired action with magic.

Comment: If magic can be explained by some sort of field that is measurable, and responds the same way for everyone, then the study of it is science, not magic. This may not be what you want. Also, not sure that the 'hard-science' tag quite works with this question.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question.   You want to provide detailed explanation, cool. Could you please  provide a detailed explanation? The current technobabble doesn't explain anything really.

Comment: I see three problems with this approach: one, the mathematical framework underpinning natural forces is interconnected in complicated ways, two, nobody is likely to be interested in it. There is a reason physicists rely on metaphors when explaining QFT to laypeople. But the biggest problem is that even if you succeed, magic will stop being...well, magical. There's no wonder, no glamour, no abrupt changing of reality through the power of words, just Lie groups, gauge symmetries and renormalisation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a simple chemical reaction, such as the combustion of water. In our world it can be represented as:

2H₂ + O₂ -> 2H₂O

Your world has magic, so why not introduce it as an element. Because fire is clearly slightly magical, let's have combustion produce a little bit of magic.

2H₂ℳ + O₂ℳ -> 2H₂0ℳ + ℳ

Magic is bound into each gas, and due to (some unexplained phenomena), Hydrogen and Oxygen gas both have 1 Magic.
A water molecule also has 1 Magic associated with it, but the chemical process of combustion has a total of 3 Magic going in, so one magic is released to ensure all the numbers balance.

This means that if a mage wants to produce 'free' magic, they can burn stuff (in this case pure hydrogen), and if they want to split water (eg with electrolysis) back into hydrogen and oxygen, then they have to supply magic - either from internal reserves (probably the body doing some chemical reaction) or by having some other reaction producing magic involved and letting the magic mix.

So, this isn't QFT as your question desired, but it is a hard science way of doing magic that can tell you very precise amounts and can tell you what magic enables.
It doesn't tell you what magic *is* though. Perhaps it is a field that surrounds a magic user/object. Who knows!

This also doesn't tell you how to assign how much magic a molecule has. In the real world we use valance electrons and electronegativity to figure out how many bonds an element can have. Perhaps in your world, atoms also have similar 'slots' that can explain why Hydrogen gas and water both have exactly one magic associated with it. Be aware that you are reinventing chemistry here, and there may be some surprising side effects. You should probably make sure that photosynthesis still works and that humans walking (reduction of ATP IIRC) doesn't produce or require heaps of magic.

There are other ways you can introduce it, but I'd suggest sticking to chemical methods (eg similar to an element (presented here) or thermochemistry or electrochemistry). Nuclear and Quantum stuff is weird and inscrutable to most normal people. (Oh hey, our mage can transmute Uranium into Plutonium but can't cast a fireball?!).

Comment: Looking forward to wizards discovering the magic equivalent of the lanthanide contraction.